# Clarification for "solving the equation for $t < \sigma_0$ is equivalent to solving the reversed-time equation"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to understand some theory of linear ODE for control theory and I got stuck.

In the book *Mathematical Control Theory*, Eduardo Sontag shows that there is a unique solution for the initial value problem for a linear ODE:

$$\dot{\xi}(t) = A(t)\xi(t), \quad \xi(\sigma_0) = x_0 \label{1}\tag{I}$$

defined in the interval $[\sigma_0,\infty) \subseteq I$, where $\xi(t) : I \to R^n$ and $A = (\alpha_{ij})$ is a matrix of measurable and locally essentially bounded functions $\alpha_{ij} : I \to R$. My problem comes when he says the following:

> Solving the equation \eqref{1} for $t < \sigma_0$ is equivalent to solving the reversed-time equation $\dot{\xi} = −A\xi$, which is also globally Lipschitz. Thus, solutions are defined on $(-\infty, \infty)$. (p.487).

I can see that the equation $\dot{\xi} = −A\xi$ indeed has a unique solution for an initial value, however **I don't see clear why is this last equation equivalent to solving $(I)$ for $t < \sigma_0$.**

I suppose there should be a IVP of the form $\dot{\xi} = −A\xi$ that is equivalent to solving $(I)$ for $t < \sigma_0$, so I was thinking in the following IVP:

$$\dot{\xi}(t) = -A(t)\xi(t), \quad \xi(\sigma_0) = x_0 \quad \label{2}\tag{II}$$

On one hand, \eqref{2} has a unique solution $\xi_{II}$, and it fulfills that $\dot{\xi}_{II}(\sigma_0) = -A(\sigma_0)x_0$. Also $\dot{\xi}_{II}(t_0) = -A(t_0)\xi_{II}(t_0)$ if $t_0 > \sigma_0$, however this last thing means $-\dot{\xi}_{II}(t_0) = A(t_0)\xi_{II}(t_0)$, therefore $\xi_{II}(t_0)$ is a point solution for \eqref{1} but with a negative in the left, does that mean that a solution for $t_0 \geq \sigma_0$ in \eqref{2} is the same as "solving" the equation \eqref{1} for a $t_0 < \sigma_0$?

As I said, I'm still confused about the equivalence. I would appreciate any clarifications, this must be very simple however I've been stuck thinking of where does that equivalence come from.

Comment: Just a hint: I think that, in the book, the Author is informally saying ''here, whatever we are saying about (existence of) solution forward in time, also holds backward in time''.
Now for a non-autonomous system (let us fix w.l.o.g., $\sigma^0=0$, then a time translation should do the general case):
$$
\dot x(t)=f(t,x(t)),\;\; x(0)=x_0,
$$
the time-inversion system, should be
$$\dot z(t)=-f(-t,z(t)),\;\;z(0)=x_0.
$$
(II) is simply not correct, I think.

Comment: @MatteoDR thanks!, this makes sense. I just have two questions: is $z(t) = x(-t)$?, and by translation you mean that, if we wanted to get the general solution $x(\sigma_0) = x_0$ we just solve $\dot{x}(t-\sigma_0) = f(t,x(t-\sigma_0))$? and this indeed has a solution for $t < \sigma_0$ because of $\dot{z}(t-\sigma_0) = f(-t,z(t-\sigma_0))$?

Comment: Yes, it is $x(-t)=z(t)$ and this can be seen by differentiating, since the two functions satisfy the same Cauchy problem (which we suppose has unique solution (forward in time)). For the time translation, I think one should consider the reflexion $t\mapsto 2\sigma_0-t$. Basically the unique reflexion of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\sigma_0$ as fixed point. But I should check

Comment: I am not a specialist in differential equations and my arguments below are not rigorous but handwaving. So as I see the issue.
Suppose that $\dot{\xi}(t) = A(t)\xi(t)$ and $\xi(\sigma_0) = x_0$.
We already know that $\dot{\xi}(t)$ is uniquely determined for $t\le \sigma_0$ and need to show that is uniquely determined for 
$t\le \sigma_0$. For this purpose we put $\eta(t)=\xi(\sigma_0-t)$. Then 
$$\dot{\eta(t)}=\dot{\xi(\sigma_0-t)}=-A(\sigma_0-t)\xi(\sigma_0-t)=-A(\sigma_0-t)\eta(t).$$

Comment: We see that the equation $\dot{\eta(t)}=-A(\sigma_0-t)\eta(t)$, $\eta(0)=x_0$ has a unique solution by the already shown result. It follows that $\dot{\xi}(t)$ is uniquely determined also for $t\le \sigma_0$.

Comment: Note that usually the existence theorems and maximal solution statements are for the domain of the solution extending in both directions. Then such alchemy "after the fact" (=proof of the existence theorem) is not necessary. However such a flip in the time direction may be necessary for some inequalities inside the proof, if for instance the Picard integral equation is only considered for forwards time, backwards integration requiring a time inversion to define it correctly.

Comment: @AlexRavsky sorry to answer two days later, after looking at it, I think you are right. The idea is that the IVP $\dot{\xi}(t)= A(t)\xi(t),$ $\xi(\sigma_0) = x_0$ with solution $\xi$ defined  in $[\sigma_0,\infty)$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$ by defining $\xi(t) = \eta(t)$ for $t < \sigma_0$ where $\eta$ is the solution of the IVP you give. The nice part is that $\eta(\sigma_0) = x_0$ so the initial values condition coincides! I'm going to stay with your argument.

Comment: More precisely, $\xi(t)=\eta(\sigma_0-t)$, for $t<\sigma_0$.